# Return value from other sheet within same workbook - pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I would like to call and return a value from another sheet within the same workbook using `Pandas`.

For calculations from the same sheet I can simply do this:
`df.loc[index, 'Ø Preis NOK\ngross']=f"=(D{index+2}+F{index+2})/2"`

In the excel workbook the formula for doing what I want is: `=H2/'Rate+Tax'!$E$3` where `Rate+Tax` is the other sheet.

However, when I do this I get an error when opening the excel file: `df.loc[index, 'Ø price NOK\nnet']=f"=(H{index+2}/\'Rate+Tax\'!$E$3"`

Note: When saving the excel I would also like to see the formula when I click on the cell.
I'm saving the excel file with `openpyxl`

How can I easily fix this problem?

Comment: Well, you have an extra parenthesis, might this be the issue? The text of the error on file open could help, too.